# Not able to run flask app on apache with cent os

Tags: apache, flask, centos6

I am trying to run flask app on apache with centos. I followed this guide http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/ but with no success. The service isn't running on port 5000 when i do htop .  I even tried simply running the app through terminal but there is no response from server.

**myapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

**myapp.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myapp')
from myapp import app as application
```

Added following code in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
<Virtualhost *>
    ServerName my.app
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=mapp group=mapp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/myapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order allow,deny 
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

I've also added my.app(ServerName) in **/etc/hosts** as:

```
127.0.0.1          my.app
```

Comment: Could you paste your source code here?

Comment: @MrPyCharm I've added the code